# Can I use ruby module 'Bunny' for EventHubs?

Tags: ruby, linux, azure

I tried to use Bunny for Azure EventHubs, and actually Bunny supports AMQP 0.9.1 and AMQP 0.9.1 has compatibility with AMQP 1.0.

However, I had an error when I executed following code.

```
conn = Bunny.new('amqps://[username]:[password]@[namespace].servicebus.windows.net/[virtualhost]', :ssl => true)
conn.start

AMQ::Protocol::FrameTypeError: Must be one of [:method, :headers, :body, :heartbeat]
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/amq-protocol-1.9.2/lib/amq/protocol/frame.rb:64:in `decode_header'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bunny-1.6.3/lib/bunny/transport.rb:243:in `read_next_frame'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bunny-1.6.3/lib/bunny/session.rb:947:in `init_connection'
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bunny-1.6.3/lib/bunny/session.rb:275:in `start'
    from (irb):5
    from /opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Or can't it use for EventHubs?

My environment is as follows:

- CentOS: 6.6
- Ruby: 2.1.2
- Bunny: 1.6.3
- Bunny protocol version: 0.9.1

Comment: Just for searchability - this error also occurs if you accidentally connect to the management endpoint instead of the AMQP endpoint! 

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the experimental plug-in that is creating the AMQP 1.0 compliance

see: https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html

plug-in source: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0